# execute shell command without affecting OS environment

Tags: python, cloud-foundry

I use CloudFoundry CLI. It allows to do stuff like pushing applications, creating services etc. 
However when executing its command it uses the credentials, spaces of the currently logged in user.

I use all shell commands like this

```
def exec_cmd(*args, **kwargs):
    proc = subprocess.run(args, check=True, **kwargs)
    return proc.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip() if kwargs.get('capture_output', False) else None
```

And then do something like `exec_cmd('cf', 'curl' ...)`.

However when doing operations like `push` etc. it uses the environment of `cf` and my attempts to change `space` for example changes it for all terminal sessions.

How to run it on its own without affecting the global state? (The reason I need this because regular python API is not as complete as CF CLI and less convenient)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `$CF_HOME` to have a separate file for credentials/space etc.

From the docs https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/getting-started.html :

After you log in, the cf CLI saves a config.json file that contains your API endpoint, org, space values, and access token.

If you change these settings, the config.json file is updated accordingly.

By default, config.json is located in the ~/.cf directory. You can relocate the config.json file using the CF_HOME environment variable.

Comment: but it still affects the global no? like i mean changing spaces in a single terminal affects all other terminals no matter where the credentials are located. or it doesn't? because now it does.

Comment: The default `CF_HOME` is `~/.cf` & by default everything shares this one config. That's why you see the "global" behavior you're describing. If you change `CF_HOME` to some place unique that nothing else is using, then you have no overlap and "global" behavior. In your Python script, you could create a temp directory and set `CF_HOME` to that then you should have a unique home for what you execute from that script.